# Why is たい used here?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> 赤の見出し語の右上の赤色の数字　身につけ**たい**学年

It's the explanation for the red numbers used in my dictionary.

Who wants? Why isn't it just 身につける学年?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It expresses "generally expected". The usage is mostly similar to the English "you may want to include more contexts" as seen in comments on JSE. Technically the subject is *you* (which is the person who does the knowing) both in Japanese and in English, but of course the person who judges *you want* is the speaker.

Similarly:

- 知っておきたい単語 Words you want to know
- 今年行きたい場所 Places you want to visit this year

Answer (score 4):

It is the school year when "you" *want* to have acquired [the meaning of the entry].

There's no reason for using a pronoun.  You could just say

> the school year in which it is desirable to have acquired ....

I would hypothesize, since we don't necessarily  know the mind of the people that wrote this, that 身につける学年 is too strong:  *the school year in which it is acquired*.   Perhaps for someone struggling to learn that would be too intimidating.

身につけたい is suggesting a target year; 身につける学年 seems far too confident about what you will achieve.